# UUEncode.Decode deleting file after failed decode

Tags: vb.net, try-catch, uuencode

I am using `UUEncode.Decode` to decode a batch of UUEncoded files. Occasionally one of the UUEncoded files is corrupt, causing `UUEncode.Decode` to terminate. I handle this with `Try .. Catch  .. End Try`, which successfully handles the failure to decode a particular UUEncoded file.

For the next step I need to delete the UUEncoded file. If the `UUEncode.Decode` was successful then I can go on to delete the UUEncoded file, but if the UUEncode.Decode failed, causing a catch, then I cannot delete the file as it is still open.

Any idea how to close the file left open by UUEncode.Decode so that I can proceed to delete it?

Here is the code:

```
Try

strOutputFilename = UUEncode.Decode(lblWorkingPath.Text & strFilename & ".uu", lblWorkingPath.Text)

Catch ex As Exception

strOutputFilename = ""

End Try


File.Delete(lblWorkingPath.Text & strFilename & ".uu")
```

Comment: Welcome! Take the [tour]. Then if you could add some code it would be helpful.

Comment: You can store the path of the files that failed decoding and delete them after (when the UUEncode object has been disposed). Even though it should be possible to release / close the stream *manually*. -- Use `Path.Combine()` to build paths.

Comment: Are you sure you want to delete the file that failed? Since you haven't actually processed it yet it seems like you might still need it, and instead maybe copy the file to a different folder and write a log message.

Comment: That sounds hopeful. How do I dispose of the UUEncode object, I'm not doing that at the moment.

Comment: Yes, definitely want to delete it!

Comment: How are you creating the object? Is it a reference to an external library? Usually to dispose it'll either be .dispose or set = nothing.

Comment: I create the object with: Dim UUEncode As New TextCodec.UUEncode and then before attempting to delete the file I (now) have UUEncode = Nothing. Unfortunately, this still doesn't allow me to delete the file.